# Total Python virgin, what is wrong with this code? "Detect Indentation error."

Tags: python, compiler-errors, pygame, indentation

What is the problem with this code, and before you ask i did this all with youtube videos and short tutorials.
It would be much appreciated if someone can help me code, in that case just ask for my skype and I'll add you, I NEED TO DO THIS! :).

At around line 253 it says requires "expectded indented block" I honestly have no idea what to do.

```
    import pygame, sys, time, random, Globals
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init(frequency=22050, size=-16, channels=10, buffer=4096)

#Classes

class MenuButton(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, image, image_dem, x, y):
        self.image = pygame.image.load(image[0]).convert_alpha()
        self.image_over = pygame.image.load(image[1]).convert_alpha()
        self.image_dem = image_dem
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, self.image_dem[0], self.image_dem[1])
    def setXY(x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def setImage(image, dem):
        self.image = pygame.image.load(image[0]).convert_alpha()
        self.image_over = pygame.image.load(image[1]).convert_alpha()
        self.image_dem = dem

class Sprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, image, image_dem, x, y):
        self.image = pygame.image.load(image).convert_alpha()
        self.image_dem = image_dem
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, self.image_dem[0], self.image_dem[1])
    def setXY(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def setImage(self, image, dem):
        self.image = pygame.image.load(image).convert_alpha()
        self.image_dem = image_dem

#Variables

GAME_LOOP = True
GAME_STATE = [ [False, 'Main_Menu' ], [False, 'About_Screen'], [False, 'Settings'], [False, 'Game'] ]

GAME_CLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()
DELTA_TIME = 0
FPS = 30

WINDOW_X = 900
WINDOW_Y = 600
WINDOW_CAPTION = 'The Intern'
WINDOW = pygame.display.set_mode([WINDOW_X, WINDOW_Y])

BLACK_BACKGROUND = pygame.image.load('asset/black.png').convert()

MAIN_MENU_BACKGROUND = pygame.image.load('main_menu_assets/background.png').convert_alpha()

MAIN_MENU_INTERN = MenuButton(['main_menu_assets/The_Intern.png', 'main_menu_assets/The_Intern.png'], [150, 50], 200, 60)
MAIN_MENU_START_BTN = MenuButton(['main_menu_assets/Start.png', 'main_menu_assets/Start.png'], [150, 50], 400, 250)
MAIN_MENU_SETTINGS_BTN = MenuButton(['main_menu_assets/Settings.png', 'main_menu_assets/Settings.png'], [150, 31], 400, 300)

SETTINGS_BACKGROUND = pygame.image.load('settings_assets/Background.png').convert()
SETTINGS_BACK_BTN = MenuButton(['settings_assets/Back.png', 'settings_assets/Back.png',], [62, 63], 10, 10)
SETTINGS_MUSIC_BTN = MenuButton(['settings_assets/Music.png', 'settings_assets/Music.png',], [309, 113], 300, 250)

#SOUND = pygame.mixer.Sound('main_menu_assets/tip.ogg')
#CHANNEL = pygame.mixer.Channel(6)


















#GAME LEVELS

LEVEL_1_BACKGROUND = pygame.image.load('game_assets/floor_l1.png').convert_alpha()
PLAYER_SPRITE = Sprite('game_assets/Male.png', [100,97], 400, 500)

LEVEL_1_ARRAY_ENEMIES = []
LEVEL_1_ARRAY_BULLETS = []


GAME_LEVEL_1 = True
GAME_LEVEL_2 = False
GAME_LEVEL_3 = False
GAME_LEVEL_4 = False
GAME_LEVEL_5 = False
GAME_LEVEL_6 = False


def level_1_gen_enemy():
    y = random.randint(-50, -100)
    x = random.randint(50, 800)
    sprite = Sprite('Enemy_l1.png', [253,234], x, y)
    LEVEL_1_ARRAY_ENEMIES.append(sprite)
    return sprite

def setGameLevel(l):
    global GAME_LEVEL_1, GAME_LEVEL_2, GAME_LEVEL_3, GAME_LEVEL_4, GAME_LEVEL_5, GAME_LEVEL_6
    if l == 1:
        GAME_LEVEL_1 = True
        GAME_LEVEL_2 = False
        GAME_LEVEL_3 = False
        GAME_LEVEL_4 = False
        GAME_LEVEL_5 = False
        GAME_LEVEL_6 = False
    if l == 2:
        GAME_LEVEL_1 = False
        GAME_LEVEL_2 = True
        GAME_LEVEL_3 = False
        GAME_LEVEL_4 = False
        GAME_LEVEL_5 = False
        GAME_LEVEL_6 = False
    if l == 3:
        GAME_LEVEL_1 = False
        GAME_LEVEL_2 = False
        GAME_LEVEL_3 = True
        GAME_LEVEL_4 = False
        GAME_LEVEL_5 = False
        GAME_LEVEL_6 = False
    if l == 4:
        GAME_LEVEL_1 = False
        GAME_LEVEL_2 = False
        GAME_LEVEL_3 = False
        GAME_LEVEL_4 = True
        GAME_LEVEL_5 = False
        GAME_LEVEL_6 = False
    if l == 5:
        GAME_LEVEL_1 = False
        GAME_LEVEL_2 = False
        GAME_LEVEL_3 = False
        GAME_LEVEL_4 = False
        GAME_LEVEL_5 = True
        GAME_LEVEL_6 = False
    if l == 6:
        GAME_LEVEL_1 = False
        GAME_LEVEL_2 = False
        GAME_LEVEL_3 = False
        GAME_LEVEL_4 = False
        GAME_LEVEL_5 = False
        GAME_LEVEL_6 = True

#games
#The first level is displayed below
minionCounter_level1 = 0
gameWon = False

def void_game_level_1():
    WINDOW.blit(LEVEL_1_BACKGROUND, [0, 0])
    if gameWon == False:
        WINDOW.blit(PLAYER_SPRITE.image, [PLAYER_SPRITE.x, PLAYER_SPRITE.y])
        level_1_gen_enemy()
        if (minionCounter_level1 > 15):
            gameWon = True
    else:



def void_game_level_2():
    a = 0   

def void_game_level_3():    
    a = 0

def void_game_level_4():
    a = 0

def void_game_level_5():
    a = 0

def void_game_level_6():
    a = 0

#loops
#These events show what will happen if a key or button is struck.
def void_game_loop_level_1(event):
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            PLAYER_SPRITE.x = PLAYER_SPRITE.x - 5
        if event.key == pygame.K_a:
            PLAYER_SPRITE.x = PLAYER_SPRITE.x - 5
        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            PLAYER_SPRITE.x = PLAYER_SPRITE.x + 5
        if event.key == pygame.K_d:
            PLAYER_SPRITE.x = PLAYER_SPRITE.x + 5


def void_game_loop_level_2(event):
    a = 0

def void_game_loop_level_3(event):
    a = 0

def void_game_loop_level_4(event):
    a = 0

def void_game_loop_level_5(event):
    a = 0

def void_game_loop_level_6(event):
    a = 0    




















#Functions

def getGameState(name):
    for state in GAME_STATE:
        if state[1] == name:
            return state
    return state[0]

def setGameState(name):
    global WINDOW
    for state in GAME_STATE:
        if state[1] == name:
            state[0] = True
        else:
            state[0] = False

#Initilizers

def main_init():
    pygame.display.set_caption(WINDOW_CAPTION)
    setGameState('Main_Menu')
    pygame.key.set_repeat(50,50)

def main_menu_event(event):
    if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        start = MAIN_MENU_START_BTN.rect
        settings = MAIN_MENU_SETTINGS_BTN.rect
        mouse = event.pos
        if start.collidepoint(mouse):
            pygame.mixer.music.stop()
            setGameState('Game')
        if settings.collidepoint(mouse):
            setGameState('Settings')

def main_menu_loop():
    WINDOW.blit(MAIN_MENU_BACKGROUND, [0,0])
    WINDOW.blit(MAIN_MENU_INTERN.image, [MAIN_MENU_INTERN.x, MAIN_MENU_INTERN.y])
    WINDOW.blit(MAIN_MENU_START_BTN.image, [MAIN_MENU_START_BTN.x, MAIN_MENU_START_BTN.y])
    WINDOW.blit(MAIN_MENU_SETTINGS_BTN.image, [MAIN_MENU_SETTINGS_BTN.x, MAIN_MENU_SETTINGS_BTN.y])

def gaming_event(event):
    if(GAME_LEVEL_1 == True):
        void_game_loop_level_1(event)
    if(GAME_LEVEL_2 == True):
        void_game_loop_level_2(event)
    if(GAME_LEVEL_3 == True):
        void_game_loop_level_3(event)
    if(GAME_LEVEL_4 == True):
        void_game_loop_level_4(event)
    if(GAME_LEVEL_5 == True):
        void_game_loop_level_5(event)
    if(GAME_LEVEL_6 == True):
        void_game_loop_level_6(event)

def gaming_loop():
    if(GAME_LEVEL_1 == True):
        void_game_level_1()
    if(GAME_LEVEL_2 == True):
        void_game_level_2()
    if(GAME_LEVEL_3 == True):
        void_game_level_3()
    if(GAME_LEVEL_4 == True):
        void_game_level_4()
    if(GAME_LEVEL_5 == True):
        void_game_level_5()
    if(GAME_LEVEL_6 == True):
        void_game_level_6()

def settings_event(event):
    if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        back = SETTINGS_BACK_BTN.rect
        music = SETTINGS_MUSIC_BTN.rect
        mouse = event.pos
        if back.collidepoint(mouse):
            setGameState('Main_Menu')
        if music.collidepoint(mouse):
            if Globals.MASTER_SOUND == True:
                pygame.mixer.music.stop()
                Globals.MASTER_SOUND = False
            else:
                pygame.mixer.music.play()
                MASTER_SOUND = True

def settings_loop():
    WINDOW.blit(SETTINGS_BACKGROUND, [0,0])
    WINDOW.blit(SETTINGS_BACK_BTN.image, [SETTINGS_BACK_BTN.x, SETTINGS_BACK_BTN.y])
    WINDOW.blit(SETTINGS_MUSIC_BTN.image, [SETTINGS_MUSIC_BTN.x, SETTINGS_MUSIC_BTN.y])


#Testing Function
def p():
    print 'ur'

def game_loop():

    #GAME_LEVEL_1.setInit([p()])
    #GAME_LEVEL_1.runInit()

    about_screen = pygame.image.load('main_menu_assets/AboutScreen.png').convert()
    WINDOW.blit(about_screen, [0,0])
    pygame.display.flip()
    time.sleep(1)
    WINDOW.blit(about_screen, [1000,1000])

    while GAME_LOOP == True:
        DELTA_TIME = GAME_CLOCK.tick(FPS)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit
                sys.exit()
            if getGameState('Main_Menu')[0] == True:    
                main_menu_event(event)
            if getGameState('Game')[0] == True:
                gaming_event(event)
            if getGameState('Settings')[0] == True:
                settings_event(event)
        if getGameState('Main_Menu')[0] == True:
            main_menu_loop()
        if getGameState('Game')[0] == True:
            gaming_loop()
        if getGameState('Settings')[0] == True:
            settings_loop()

        pygame.display.flip()

#Main

def main():
    pygame.mixer.music.load('main_menu_assets/main_menu_song.ogg')
    if Globals.MASTER_SOUND:
        pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)
    main_init()
    game_loop()

main()
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong on line 253, but right on line 1, you have an indent you shouldn't.

Comment: Can you just post some code around the line? You're probably mixing tabs and spaces.

Comment: This is a large piece of code. Please show us the actual traceback so we can help you identify what's going wrong here. See also: http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.1/ref/indentation.html

Comment: Your very first line is indented - take away all the space in front of it. In python, "whitespace" is a key part of the syntax!

Comment: I see a problem at line 166 actually, you have an `else` left there, right at the end of defining the function `void_game_level_1()`.

Comment: When I copied this code into an editor and tried running it I got an indentation error at line 1. When I fixed that, I found an indentation error at line 170 cause by an `else:` a few lines earlier that had no code after it. Remove the `else:` or add (indented) code.

Comment: Don't edit your question to highlight the problem after it's been pointed out. That's what the answers are for. Editing the question for that just makes things confusing.

Answer (score 5):

```
def void_game_level_1():
    WINDOW.blit(LEVEL_1_BACKGROUND, [0, 0])
    if gameWon == False:
        WINDOW.blit(PLAYER_SPRITE.image, [PLAYER_SPRITE.x, PLAYER_SPRITE.y])
        level_1_gen_enemy()
        if (minionCounter_level1 > 15):
            gameWon = True
    else:
```

You forgot to finish this function. In the future, look at the line the error message is telling you to look at, then look at the lines above it, since the problem is frequently on an earlier line and only detected on the line the error is talking about. Also, post the full text of any error messages you get.

Comment: I still receive, "expected indented block", no error codes showing anywhere else

Comment: @user3089190: If so, you didn't fix this function correctly. Whatever errors your code may have, this and line 1 are the only parts that cause a parse error.

Comment: I had copied and pasted the code in the exact same area as the previous block of code. But as for line one, I don't know where the indentation is.

Comment: "I had copied and pasted the code in the exact same area as the previous block of code" - why? What did you expect that to do? (I didn't finish the function for you; I have no idea what you want the function to do. I've just pointed out the problem.)

Comment: @AtomicCoffee: look at the first line of the code in your question. Do you see spaces before `import pygame, sys, ...`? I do. That's indentation.

Comment: Thank you guys, I honestly don't know if i'll be able to fix this but I don't want to bug you. So i'll keep trying.